# using a variable from callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

am trying to get data that my get text give me i generate 2 json files from an api in php  i get them with my function and can display it as an alert but i want to dry a chart with it in the function dessin () but i can't get the values of my dataid and datanom 
thanks for your help ;)

```js
getText = function(url, callback) // How can I use this callback?
{
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      callback(request.responseText); // Another callback here
    }
  };
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.send();
}

function mycallback(dataid) { //this is the data that am trying to use in 
  alert(dataid);
}

function mycallbacknom(datanom) {
  var datajsonnom = JSON.parse(datanom);
  alert(datajsonnom);
}
   getText('http://localhost/id.json',mycallback);
   getText('http://localhost/nom.json',mycallbacknom);

function dessin() {
  //var lab = datajsonnom;

  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: dataid, //i want to put the dataid here
          datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: data, // and the datanom here
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Where exactly are you calling these functions?

Comment: i use mycallback as a method in my getText function, i can get the data in the 2 callback functions but i want to use it in my third function to draw the chart is that mak eny sense ?

Comment: Right - now you've added the `getText()` calls it makes more sense. All you need to do is just call `dessin()` from the two `mycallback` functions, and pass in whatever data you need.

Comment: i've tried that it worked but it dons't give me the result sparetly it gives me the 2 variables in one and i don't know why am sure am missing something...